# How to dynamically generate code for object oriented tool?

Tags: java, oop, generics

I am kind of stuck in a dilemma. I want to create a tool that would generate code on the fly by taking various parameters from the user. The codes have a few similar features and few things need to be altered from one code to other to other. Based on the parameters, I can have 15 different codes. Till now I have been using file handling in Java to implement this as I have the created codes in different files but this doesn't seem to be a great method. Can you please suggest something that is better than this??

Comment: You are not very clear about what's your input and what's your output. Do you have some kind of model that you want to merge with a template?

Comment: I am creating a tool for testing the validity of hash functions. My inputs are the various types of constructions and algorithms that the user would want to implement. Based on the choice of algo and construction, code has to be generated and then tested. I am doing the generation using text files but I want to change that.

Comment: @user1394721 what problem are you facing please be specific.

Comment: @amod0017 There is no problem as such.. I want to generate code at run time which I am doing using file handling. I already have the code that I want in my java classes stored in text files. All I am doing is reading from them and creating the java class. But instead of this I am looking for a better method or a better data structure that can be used to execute the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 1.6 you can compile in memory whatever you want. Take a look at this code:

http://code.google.com/p/cachos/source/browse/trunk/cachos/src/com/peyrona/cachos/InMemoryCompiler.java

http://code.google.com/p/cachos/source/browse/trunk/cachos/src/com/peyrona/cachos/InMemoryExecutor.java

In this example you can see how you can compile a source code stored in a String in memory, without using the disk.

Source (Spanish): http://www.javahispano.org/portada/2011/12/12/compilar-y-ejecutar-codigo-java-en-memoria.html

I think this is what you're looking for.